# com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.seed'), stack:<unknown>@939:615

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-code-push

When I run the same app from codepush built with jenkins, it always crash after performing a specific set of action. But when I try to debug this same app by building locally, through Android Studio/Xcode, with an emu or with a phone, this same error doesnt occur.

This is the error I get by from the android studio when running the version downloaded from bitly

```
08-01 12:27:11.980 1103-1119/? I/WindowManager: addWindow: window=Window{266f386 u0 
Application Error: com.driverapp.dev}
08-01 12:27:11.980 1103-1124/? I/WindowManager: Focus moving from null to Window{266f386 u0 
Application Error: com.driverapp.dev}
08-01 12:27:11.980 1103-1124/? I/WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{266f386 u0 Application 
Error: com.driverapp.dev}
08-01 12:27:11.987 9010-9010/? D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED 
ActivityRecord{3894976 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d1a6b77 
{com.driverapp.dev/com.driverapp.MainActivity}}
08-01 12:27:11.991 5344-5344/? D/CrashHandler-UserSubmitReceiver: description: Process: 
com.driverapp.dev
          Flags: 0x38c8be44
          Package: com.driverapp.dev v32 (1.1.28)
          Build: LeEco/Le2_CN1/le_x6:6.0/

          com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.seed'), stack:
          <unknown>@939:615
          a@2:850
          <unknown>@2:392
          t@2:399
          <unknown>@938:43
          a@2:850
          <unknown>@2:322
          t@2:399
          @934:4748
          value@934:4993
           ......

           at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
           at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
           at com.facebook.
08-01 12:27:11.992 5344-5344/? D/CrashHandler-MatcherString: match1: name: sh  >>> sh 
<<<|match2: signal 13 \(SIGPIPE\)|description: Process: com.driverapp.dev
                                                         Flags: 0x38c8be44
                                                         Package: com.driverapp.dev v32 (1.1.28)
                                                         Build: LeEco/Le2_CN1/le_x6:6.0/
```

I can't figure out what the error is. Any help is very much appreciated.